# How to calculate the average stretch of a Quad?

Tags: math, colors

Not sure if I formulate the correct answer but basically I need to know how to calculate the average size of a stretch quad, or something like taking the 2 diagonals AC and BD how can I calculate the average of them

[image]

The blue square show its original size and the pink lines shows when its deform, I need to calculate some sort of average so I can change its color in relation to how is deform if expands change to a lighter color if contracts change to darker color, hope that makes sense

Comment: It deforms but maintains the same area ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what the question here is.

If you're asking how to find the average diagonal length, just find [the length of each diagonal](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm), add them together and divide by two.

If you're asking how to determine the area of the resultant shape, [here are several formulas for finding the area of an arbitrary quadrilateral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Area_of_a_convex_quadrilateral).  They are all equivalent to the formula

```
Area = 1/2 * |AC x BD|
```

Where `x` means the [cross-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Comment: I want to know how much it deforms so I can change its color accordingly, if the square goes bigger change to a lighter, if it shrinks change go darker so I think the first option is best for my needs

Answer (score 0):

A quadrilateral will have a 2nd order symmetric strain tensor:

```
| Exx Exy |
| Exy Eyy |
```

`Exx` is the strain in the x-direction; `Eyy` is the strain in the y-direction; `Exy` is the shear strain that occurs when one of the angles that is originally 90 degrees changes its value.

If you have large strains, you'll need a Lagrangian point of a view and a Green-Lagrange large strain measure.

See Malvern's Continuum Mechanics for definitions of each term.  I'd give you the formulas, but I don't have LaTeX available here.

Comment: I think we can safely assume that 99% of the readers here have never encountered tensors, so without further explanation, you might as well be speaking Greek.